# Flask-Login login_user() throws TypeError when passing a user object

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to use the Flask-Login extension to handle my user sessions but when I call the login_user(user) method it throws the following error

```
File "app.py", line 55, in login_user
login_user(user)
TypeError: login_user() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But the Flask-Login documentation says it takes in a user object as a parameter and all of the implementations I've found online use the method in this manner so I can't understand where my error lies.

This is my User model:

```
class Users(db.Model):
 __tablename__ = "users"
 u_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 username = db.Column(db.String(80))
 passhash = db.Column(db.String(256))
 fname = db.Column(db.String(80))
 lname = db.Column(db.String(80))

 def hash_password(self, password):
     self.passhash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

 def verify_password(self, password):
     return pwd_context.verify(password, self.passhash)

 @property
 def is_active(self):
     return True

 @property
 def is_authenticated(self):
     return True

 @property
 def is_anonymous(self):
     return False

 def get_id(self):
     return str(self.u_id)
```

and here is the login function:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return models.Users.query.filter_by(u_id =int(user_id)).first()

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_user():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    user = models.Users.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
        return jsonify({'success': False})

    login_user(user)
    return jsonify({'success': True})
```

Can anyone help shed some light on where I'm going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error derives from a name conflict. The Flask `login_user` is being shadowed by your view which shares the same name. Python rightly assumes you're trying to make a recursive call albeit with a wrong signature. Rename your view function `login_user` to something else.

Comment: This solved it, I didn't even realize I had given the login function the same name. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, you are recursively calling `login_user()` which doesn't take any arguments. You are suppose to call your `load_user(user)` instead.

```
load_user(user)
```